# Override method in a third party module

Tags: ruby, module, overriding

I'm trying to override a method that is inside two modules from a third party library.

It looks like this :

```
module Omnigollum
  module Helpers
    def kick_back
      redirect !request.referrer.nil? && request.referrer !~ /#{Regexp.escape(settings.send(:omnigollum)[:route_prefix])}\/.*/ ?
        request.referrer:
        '/'
      halt
    end
  end
end
```

This method is used by other functions from this library. I need to completely override it.

I tried lot of solution given by other stackoverflow thread, but so far nothing works.

Here is what I have now :

```
module OmnigollumOverride
  module Helpers
    def kick_back
      puts '=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-==-=-'
      puts '=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-==-=-'
    end
  end
end

include Omnigollum
Omnigollum.module_eval { include OmnigollumOverride }
```

I just print some line to test if the method is correctly overridden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
include Omnigollum
Omnigollum.module_eval { include OmnigollumOverride }
```

call this once:

```
Omnigollum::Helpers.prepend OmnigollumOverride::Helpers
```

Prepending module places it on top of inheritance hierarchy. Whether you want to re-use the original behaviour, you might do:

```
def kick_back
  return super if SOME_CONDITION # call original method

  puts '=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-==-=-'
  puts '=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-==-=-'
end
```